# django make available few of the django admin forms to the users at a different url

Tags: django, django-admin, django-formwizard, django-admin-tools

Django admin is really awesome. It provides hell lot of features, we can play around with data the extensively.

Instead of writing model forms? Is it possible for me to serve some of the forms that django has with all the CRUD functionality to a non admin user.

Say I have three classes in my model.

Class A, Class B, and Class C.

In the admin I can equally play around with A, B, and C.

But in case, if I want the logged in user to play around with class C, the user is not admin, and I do not want him to see the admin part? So in a different url, is it possible for me, to import the forms from admin and serve???

Let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a User, you can give different access to any part of your app in the user permission tab. This mechanism should do what you want.

If you want to go further and play with the display of your app while keeping something similar to the django admin, you can use the templates of django admin in a view in order to give access to only a part of your model and add more design and custom functions.

In this case, I'll suggest you to make a copy of the templates located in `django\contrib\admin\templates\admin` and then you can modifiy them as you want.